# Ubuntu booting to GRUB after deleting partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have previously had a parallell install of win 10 and ubuntu. After deleting the ubuntu partition, my system only boots to GRUB. I have tried to repair using boot repair and also reinstall Ubuntu, but to no avail. I have also played around with grub rescue, but realised that I have no idea what I'm doing. I don't know if this helps but here is the log by boot repair: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/BjKpnVtNbZ/.

Comment: It looks like you have old MBR partitioning for sda & sdb. But have newer gpt partitioning on sdc. And sdc has an ESP for UEFI boot with Windows. Microsoft requires gpt for UEFI boot. But you do not show a Windows entry in UEFI boot menu. So you need Windows repairs using your Windows repair flash drive.

Comment: Boot windows 10 recovery media & use its tools to fix the problem. Ubuntu was deleted as I read your post, thus it can no longer help (*unless you re-install it*).  You should have made windows 10 own the boot process before deleting the Ubuntu partition (*windows has commands for this*).